# .NET MD5 signature does not match OpenSSL MD5 signature

Tags: c#, cryptography, openssl, md5

I have to sign messages for a web service. The service uses OpenSSL MD5 signatures. I generate the OpenSSL one from a PEM private key file:

```
openssl.exe dgst -md5 -hex -out signature.txt -sign privKey.pem textToSign.txt
```

Which generates the following signature:

```
7078388bd081d4b805feb020ab47352320919e4638e36b59d66a684c9bb12a745aaf172e4da2686c3e3750bf627c980a19700f6d8bbd0b62d8714a965a34be2e9f4147ac054c4af1050cdcebd9b475f0ef28e520681b0d67104b8e633ee592bb3ec2c517fb8cf7b13bd86424f00c89518e063d55e7922adab7cf607c85920862
```

I want to implement this in my code. My actual code looks like (the private key in the pfx file is the same as the one in the pem file):

```
private static string Sign(string stringToSign)
{
    X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("keys.pfx", "", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
    byte[] signedData;
    using (MD5 hasher = MD5.Create())
    using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey)
    {
        signedData = rsa.SignData(data, hasher);
    }
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);
}
```

This code produces the following signature...

```
cHg4i9CB1LgF/rAgq0c1IyCRnkY442tZ1mpoTJuxKnRarxcuTaJobD43UL9ifJgKGXAPbYu9C2LYcUqWWjS+Lp9BR6wFTErxBQzc69m0dfDvKOUgaBsNZxBLjmM+5ZK7PsLFF/uM97E72GQk8AyJUY4GPVXnkirat89gfIWSCGI=
```

...which does not match the OpenSLL one.
What should I do to match the OpenSSL one? Also I tried to use OpenSSL.NET, but I did not find any resources/tutoral for signing.

SOLVED

The correct code is:

```
    private static string Sign(string stringToSign)
    {
        X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2("#02299991.pfx", "#02299991", X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToSign);
        byte[] signedData;
        using (MD5 hasher = MD5.Create())
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = (RSACryptoServiceProvider)cert.PrivateKey)
        {
            signedData = rsa.SignData(data, hasher);
        }
        return ByteArrayToString(signedData); //Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);
    }

    public static string ByteArrayToString(byte[] signedBytes)
    {
        StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(signedBytes.Length * 2);
        foreach (byte b in signedBytes)
            hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
        return hex.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Consider replacing MD5 with SHA-2. The collision attacks against MD5 can lead to practical attacks against digital signatures building on top of MD5.

Comment: It is not my choice, I have to cooperate with a "legacy" service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your OpenSSL output is a *hex* string:

```
openssl.exe dgst -md5 -hex -out signature.txt -sign privKey.pem textToSign.txt
                       ^
```

While your C# output is in Base64:

```
return Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);
               ^
```

---

Convert your `byte[]` output to a hex string:

- [How do you convert Byte Array to Hexadecimal String, and vice versa?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/311165/119527)

Comment: Thank you! Using hex string representation solved it!